# Why used internal memory is greater than total size of apps?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My phone reports 131MB internal memory use but when I add up the sizes of all apps in internal memory, it doesn't add up even to 100MB. I don't have any media whatsoever in the phone. What is the culprit for my ~30MB loss?

**Edit:** The storage space started to drop significantly after I have upgraded the stock Android Market app to Google Play Store app. After this, I think Google Play Services has been downloaded, which takes up a lot of space. Still, it should not be taking up that much space. Strangely, when I plugged my phone to my PC via USB, the reported internal storage dropped to 70MB again. I can't find an explanation for this.

Comment: Did you check all the files (including hidden files and cache)?

Comment: Most likely cache as @LorenoHeer said. Could also be photos, music files, videos and etc. Depending on your device. Look in the storage  option under Settings. It should tell you how much free/total space you have, then it should break it down into apps, media files, misc and etc.

Comment: Actually, when I plugged in my phone to my PC via USB, it dropped to 70MB. I can't find an explanation for this.